# Magento 2 custom module installation failed

Tags: magento2, module

I made my own Magento 2 module for adding a custom field to an existing table *sales_order_item*. When I try to enable the module with the command

```
php bin/magento module:enable Test_ProductType
```

The following error occurred,

> There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace

And if I ran this command

```
php bin/magento
```

I got this output, see image:

[image]

And this is my `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Test_ProductType" setup_version="2.0.5">
 <sequence>
    <module name="Test_ProductType"/></sequence>
 </module>
</config>
```

What do I have to do to make this module working?

Comment: most probably you have listed your module as a dependency for your module. Or one class from your module has as a dependency the same class

Comment: Can you post your module xml?

Comment: I just edited my post with module.xml included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Take care when using `sequence` in multiple components because it's
>   possible to define circular dependencies. If you do, Magento aborts
>   the installation when it detects the circular dependency.

This is because your module declares itself as a dependency. So, should remove the `sequence` node. Your `module.xml` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Scandesigns_ProductType" setup_version="2.0.5"/>
</config>
```

Comment: This is genius. It worked with your code. Thanks a lot for the help. Can you explain what was wrong in my module.xml?

Comment: You should read more here about the `sequence`: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Comment: @Zhenyu, basically you told Magento that your module had a dependency to itself, which is impossible.